# Getting inserted row ID

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have created table

```
create table AA(
    id int ,
    name varchar(20),
    sname varchar(20)
)
```

Now I am inserting a new value and getting the inserted rows id:

```
declare @InsID table (InId int)
insert into AA (name, sname)select 1, 'John', 'Rock'
output inserted.id into @output
Select * from @InsID
```

But it shows me error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near 'inserted'. Does anyone know what seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @InsID table (InId int)

insert into AA (name, sname)
output inserted.id into @InsID
select 'John', 'Rock'

Select * from @InsID
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the ID column in your table is defined as an identity column, then:

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

See this article for more info: 
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/

If you really want to use the `OUTPUT` clause your syntax is wrong. The output must come immediately after the table, before the values:

```
declare @InsID table (InId int)

insert into AA (name, sname)
output inserted.id into @InsID 
select 'John', 'Rock'

Select * from @InsID
```

See [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ca8fa/2) for an example of each